# Очень долго шифруются файлы алгоритмом ГОСТ 34.12-2015 (Кузнечик) с использованием BouncyCastle/SpongyCastle в Android

Tags: java, android, шифрование

Нужно реализовать программу для шифрования файлов алгоритмами ГОСТ 28147-89 (Магма) и ГОСТ Р 34.12-2015 (Кузнечик). С использованием ГОСТ 28147-89 проблем не возникло. При использовании ГОСТ Р 34.12-2015 столкнулся с рядом проблем. По всей видимости Bouncy Castle уже включена в Andoid SDK, однако провайдер BC не содержит алгоритма GOST3412-2015. Проблема была решена удалением провайдера и добавлением новой версии:

```
BouncyCastleProvider bouncyCastleProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.removeProvider(bouncyCastleProvider.getName());
Security.addProvider(bouncyCastleProvider);
```

После этого появилась возможность шифровать с использованием GOST3412-2015, однако скорость шифрования уж очень долгая (файл размером ~5 MB шифруется ГОСТ 28147-89 примерно за 500 мс, а ГОСТ 34.12-2015 - 12 000 мс).

SpongyCastle не содержит алгоритма GOST3412-2015.

Пробовал подключить такую же версию библиотеки BouncyCastle в Java на ПК и все работает адекватно.

В чем может быть проблема? Как реализовать в Andoid ГОСТ Р 34.12-2015 (Кузнечик)? Есть ли другие библиотеки с реализацией ГОСТ Р 34.12-2015?

Шифрование:

```
public void encryptFile(File file, String pass) {
    String algorithm = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("algorithm", "GOST-28147");
    String path = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("homeDir", "/storage");
    try {
        FileInputStream fin = context.openFileInput("salt");
        byte[] salt = new byte[fin.available()];
        fin.read(salt);
        fin.close();

        fin = context.openFileInput("IV8");
        byte[] IV8 = new byte[fin.available()];
        fin.read(IV8);
        fin.close();

        fin = context.openFileInput("IV16");
        byte[] IV16 = new byte[fin.available()];
        fin.read(IV16);
        fin.close();

        SecretKey secretKey = generateSecretKey(pass, salt, algorithm);

        fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + "/" + file.getName() + "_encrypted" + algorithm);


        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm + "/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
        if (algorithm.equals("GOST-28147")) {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(IV8));
        } else if (algorithm.equals("GOST3412-2015")){
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(IV16));
        }

        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        int  b;
        byte[] d = new byte[1024*1024];
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ((b = fin.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fin.close();
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();

        timerDataBaseHelper = new TimerDataBaseHelper(context);
        db = timerDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        timerDataBaseHelper.insertTime(db, file.getAbsolutePath(), (int)file.length(), "ENCRYPTION", algorithm, (int)(stop - start));
```

Вызов в AsyncTask:

```
class EncryptTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object[]> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Шифрование началось", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object[] doInBackground(Object... args) {
        File file = (File)args[0];
        Encription encription = (Encription)args[1];
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        encription.encryptFile(file, password);
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double time = Double.valueOf(stop - start)/1000;
        Object[] arr = new Object[2];
        arr[0] = time;
        arr[1] = file;
        return arr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object[] result) {
       //Вывод результатов
    }
}
```

Comment: А чем вызвана необходимость использования отечественного алгоритма?

Comment: Если это имеет значение, то так поставлена задача в учебном проекте.